# How can I add multiple dictionaries to existing DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have a dataframe that I want to add two new dictionaries too. I can add one, but it overwrites the existing data and will not add the other. How can I fix this?

This is what I am currently trying, it performs the calculations and will create the new file but it only creates one column and none of the existing data is included. How can I fix this, is it even possible?

Thanks

```
#Fill the data from excel
data = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#Perform calculations
new_col_a = np.multiply(df['somecol'], x_rate) 
new_col_b = np.subtract(new_col_a, df['somecol'])
#create the new columns
df['col_a'] = new_col_a
df['col_b] = new_col_b
#now create new excel file
df.to_excel('new.xlsx')
```

Comment: show example of your df

Comment: It's too large, How can I do that?

Comment: use: df.head(n) where n is the number of rows

Comment: Ok, here goes, If I try posting it all I get an error; to large and StackOverflow won't let me post it all.
  Ticker Symbol  ... Working Capital
0          ZYXI  ...       7971000.0
1          ZYXI  ...       4344000.0
2          ZYXI  ...      -4323000.0
3          ZYXI  ...      -4773000.0
4          ZYXI  ...      -2352000.0

[5 rows x 111 columns]

Comment: Ok, well, new problem, this was working yesterday, now I get 'type' object is not subscriptable with 
L_adj = np.multiply(df['"colmnA'], X)
Why?

Answer (score 0):

Well actually I don't have an answer, for some reason this line

someDict= np.multiply(df['ColA'], some_rate) now throws 'type object is not subscriptable' I changed nothing so the only thing I can think of is numpy upgraded something? Bizarre!